# How to get the first descendant of a node without knowing the name from XML using LINQ

Tags: linq

I have an XML string that looks something like this:

```
<FIXML>
    <T TrdTyp = "1" etc/>
</FIXML>


<FIXML>
    <X TrdTyp = "0" etc/>
</FIXML>
```

Notice that the name of the first descendant of FIXML can be anything, in this short example it can be T or X. I need to access the attribute, TrdType, to count the number of occurrences.

Without knowing the name of the descendant of FIXML, what is the correct LINQ query to do this?

If I knew the name of the descendant, this works, but only for those that are T, I miss the X:

```
var t =
from el in clearingMessagesDoc.Elements("ClearingMessages").Elements("FIXML").Elements("T")
let trdtyp = el.Attribute("TrdTyp").Value
group trdtyp by trdtyp.Trim() into g
orderby g.Key descending
select new { 
TrdType = g.Key,
Count = g.Count() 
};
```

So I would get a count of 1 for "0" and a count of 1 for "1"

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
var t =
    from el in clearingMessagesDoc.Elements("ClearingMessages")
        .Elements("FIXML")
        .Elements()
        .First(e => e.Attribute("TrdTyp") != null)
    let trdtyp = el.Attribute("TrdTyp").Value
    group trdtyp by trdtyp.Trim() into g
    orderby g.Key descending
    select new { 
        TrdType = g.Key,
        Count = g.Count() 
    };
```

Comment: Thanks. How does that go into a query like above though? I get an error if I say

Comment: @Ivan: What error do you get? I've updated my answer with your full example code